# Delay Loading Javascript to speed my Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I'm using joomla site, and Forced to use extra java script.

My Question is:

1. How to force loading the javascript ONLY after page complete
2. I dont mean DELAY them, But make them in Queue till the page complete loading.

I tried many of links tutorial but nothing helps me.

Please,

Would you provide correct example in order to make me understand.

Example to JS file I inserted to buttom of my page:

```
<script src="/js/easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can you provide Jquery code to force all those script to wait till the page load complete?

Thank you

Tariq

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ales Kotnik answer's in great, and also if you want to do it in your own specifiec time, you can do something like that:

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

var script = document.createElement("script")
script.type = "text/javascript";

if (script.readyState){  //IE
    script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                script.readyState == "complete"){
            script.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
} else {  //Others
    script.onload = function(){
        callback();
    };
}

script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

this will load a script only when you call it, and then you activate it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.cdn.com/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadScript("http://your.cdn.com/second.js", function(){
    //initialization code
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would you please give me example for this script tag:<script src="/js/lab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Use `<script src="..." async="async"/>`. In modern browsers (HTML5)it will spawn fetching javascript files separately and won't delay loading of your HTML. You can just put script tags at the end of your `<body>`.

Comment: In Joomla, you can't just say "put in the end of body". An internal script loader takes charge of putting the modules required scripts on the page and they are placed at the head.

Comment: Why don't you create a script that injects other `<script>` tags in the `<head>` and is run on `onLoad` event.

Comment: Would you give me example for this script tag: <script src="/js/lab.js" type="text/javascript"></script>